# can't get data with drop-list using angular and php

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm building a project with angular and php. I have a "customers" table in my database. I'm trying to get all names from "Customers" table in a drop-list but it is not working. the console doesn't showing any errors for now. can anyone please check my code?

Html:

```
            <select>
              <option ng-repeat="x in customersDetails track by $index" value="{{x.customer_id}}" {{x.full_name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Controller:

```
"use strict";

angular.module('dataSystem').controller('priceOfferCtrl', function($scope,$route,$location,$http)
{
  $http({method:'GET', url:'api/customers-tab/get-priceOffer.php/'})
      .success(function(response) {

        $scope.customersDetails = response;
      })

      // This will log you the error code and trace, if there is an error.

      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('err', err)
      });
});
```

Php

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','hamatkin');

  mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_client = utf8");
  mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_connection = utf8");
  mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_results = utf8");

  if(!$connection){
    die("couldnt connect".mysqli_error);
  }
  $customer = new Customer();
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `customers``";
  $queryResult = $connection->query($query);
  $queryResult2 = array();
  if( $queryResult->num_rows>0){
    while($row = $queryResult->fetch_assoc()){
      $customer->customer_id = $row['customer_id']
      $customer->full_name =$row['full_name']

    }
  }
  header('Content-type:application/json');
  $queryResult3 = json_encode($queryResult2);
   echo json_encode($queryResult3);
?>
```

Comment: The problem is in your php code $queryResult2=array(); then?

Comment: @B.Kocaman I'm sorry I'm new with this what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should get the `response.data` instead of only the `response`, as below:

```
$scope.customersDetails = response.data;
```

Also, I recommend you to use [**`ngOptions`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of `ngRepeat` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP file has some problems;

1- There is no Customer class. (I think you dont need for this example)

2- $queryResult2 = array(); you created an Array but you didn't feed with data.

3- You encoded the empty array.

4- you tryed to encode data that was encoded.

Check the fixed example please:

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','hamatkin');

  mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_client = utf8");
  mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_connection = utf8");
  mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_results = utf8");

  if(!$connection){
    die("couldnt connect".mysqli_error);
  }

    /*
    I dont know if you have 'Customer' class    
    */
  // $customer = new Customer(); 

// $query = "SELECT * FROM `customers`";
    $query = "SELECT customer_id, full_name FROM `customers`";
  $queryResult = $connection->query($query);
  $queryResult2 = array();
  if( $queryResult->num_rows>0){
    $i = 0;
    while($row = $queryResult->fetch_assoc()){
        // if you dont have Customer class, there is no $customer->....
    // $customer->customer_id = $row['customer_id']
        // $customer->full_name =$row['full_name']

    // put the data in $queryResult2
    // $queryResult2[$i]['customer_id'] = $row['customer_id'];
    // $queryResult2[$i]['full_name'] = $row['full_name'];
// OR   
$queryResult2[] = $row;

    $i++;
    }
  }

  header('Content-type:application/json');
  $queryResult3 = json_encode($queryResult2);
  // echo json_encode($queryResult3); // you don't need to encode again.
  echo $queryResult3;
?>
```